# When we add a new kotlin class/file in androidStudio along with main acitvity, we get xml file releated to the kotlin class/file. But

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

When i started new project in android studio with tab layout activity instead of blank activity i tried to add a new activity along with main activity normally we get xml file added automatically when we add new Kotlin class, but here  I am not getting new xml file added please let me know what we can do.
[image: No loginActvity.xml]

Comment: if you want to xml auto generated  1. right click on a package that you want your new activity to be located 2. new  -> activity -> emty activity-> under source language choose kotlin

Comment: Thank you,I learned that instead of creating a new class or file, I should have created the new empty activity instead for a auto generated xml layout of respective activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new XML file, you can right click on the layout directory, and choose new layout file because in the newer versions of android studio, it no longer auto generate XML file.